# Log users into eXist-db using MD5 password (XQuery)

Tags: md5, xquery, exist-db, xquery-3.0

I need to log users into eXist-db using XQuery. Of course I can use this code:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace exist = "http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist"; 
declare namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";
declare namespace xmldb="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb";
declare option exist:serialize "method=json media-type=text/javascript";

let $userName := request:get-parameter("userName", ()) 
let $hash := request:get-parameter("hash", ()) 
let $login := xmldb:authenticate('/db', $userName, $hash)
return
    <ajax-response>
        <success>{$login}</success>
        <username>{$userName}</username>
    </ajax-response>
```

The problem is that, due to the fact that I receive the password and the username from another service, I receive them in hash form encrypted with MD5 (because they can't be passed in clear from a service to another).

But the `xmldb:authenticate` function needs the password in clear. How can I resolve this? Any idea? Is there a way to login 'manually' in eXist-db without using the `authenticate` function?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible: eXist-db does not work with hashes on the authentication functions, that would be a security risk since MD5 is not safe. In addition, eXist-db does not use MD5 internally for hashing the passwords, so validating a password would be difficult (matching two different hashing techniques is impossible)

Unfortunately there is no way to work around this with the standard functions.

Comment: So does it internally use SHA? or blowfish? What does it use?

Comment: I now found the info. Exist 1.4X did in fact use MD5. Newer versions are using RIPEMD-160. So if you got hashes in that format from the other services, you'd be fine.